# cakephp: warning 2 mysql_connect: php_network_getaddress

Tags: mysql, cakephp, database-connection

I'm getting the following ugly warning when I try to view my website on localhost.

```
mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.  [CORE\cake\libs\model\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql.php, line 561]Code | Context$config =   array(
    "persistent" => false,
    "host" => "*****",
    "login" => "*****",
    "password" => "*****",
    "database" => "*****",
    "port" => "*****",
    "driver" => "mysql",
    "prefix" => "*****"
)
```

the following is database.php

```
<?php
      class DATABASE_CONFIG {

var $default = array(
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhsot',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'database' => 'merry_flowers_db',
);
   }
  ?>
```

I don't see anything wrong with `database.php`. It is exactly the same as my other cakephp projects that connect to the same database. I'm not getting this error for my other projects. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: have you tried replacing the database.php file of a working project with this file? The application will crash, but you can at least confirm that it connects to the DB

Comment: yes, what a dumb typo. Deceze hinted me of the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'host' => 'localhsot',
                 ^^
```

Spellcheck says *boo!*